# Consuming JSON in application that only supports SOAP

Tags: json, web-services, soap

I have an application (SAP Dashboards) that will happily consume web service data, but only if there's a WSDL.
I'm trying to connect it to Azure Machine Learning which only creates web services using JSON.
There seem to be plenty of people trying to do the oppposite!

is there a way to create a simple, hopefully generic, bridge between them. I'm happy to use a bit of C#. Would be even nicer if I could do something through MS SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no standard way. I guess I need to write something myself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to convert from Xml to JSON ?

```
// To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string   
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

// To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Comment: I have no control over source or destination, so need to be able to just wrap the source.